# XCode only showing info and build settings not the rest?

Tags: ios, xcode

Anyone can explain why the other menus in xcode are not being displayed? I downloaded a tutorial file and it only shows

[image]

and not as I would expect this

[image]

I am looking for the Capabilities tab,

Comment: Have you selected the app target?

Comment: OH didn't realise this rookie mistake

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Presumably, you're looking at a project:

[image: project]

and not a target:

[image: target]

Use the popup menu (or the sidebar that's shown collapsed in my screenshots) to select your app target instead.